# How can i get the type of a Unity UI element as a generic parameter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

Im having a UIManager class, that is static. In this class, I tried to make functions that I can call wherever I want, and they shows or hides the UI elements of which name i gave it to the function.

My class looks like this:

```
public static class UIManager
{
    //If you deactivate a gameobject at the Editor, you cant activate it later. This is where UI handler comes in.
    //It hides or shows the UI elements the game has


    /// <summary>
    /// Shows the UI element of the given name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    public static void ShowUIElement(string name)
    {
        GameObject.Find(name).SetActive(true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows the UI Elements that are in the array
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="names"></param>
    public static void ShowUIElement(params string[] name)
    {
        foreach (var item in name)
        {
            GameObject.Find(item).SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hides the UI element of the given name
    /// </summary>
    public static void HideUIElement(string name)
    {
        GameObject.Find(name).SetActive(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hides the UI Elements that are in the array
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    public static void HideUIElement(params string[] name)
    {
        foreach (var item in name)
        {
            GameObject.Find(item).SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

Somehow it is not working. Maybe if I deactivate a UI element, I can't activate it, because it does not exist anymore. In Unity, the UI elements has a ".enabled" property that is changeable, but I have to know what type of UI element (button, text, panel, canvas) is, to make it disabled. This is my problem. I need a generic solution for all type of UI element, so for the function, I just pass the name of the UI element that i need to activate or deactivate, plus the type of it, so I dont have to make a function for every UI element type. Can you help me?

Comment: You should know that `GameObject.Find` is pretty slow, see the [Unity guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to enable or disable components, then you can use `Behaviour` class, because all components that can be enabled or disabled derives from it. This can be applied to all components, not only UI.

```
private Image image;
private Button button;
private Text text;
private Canvas canvas;

private void Start()
{
    DisableUIElement(image);
    DisableUIElement(button);
    DisableUIElement(text);
    DisableUIElement(canvas);
}

void DisableUIElement(Behaviour uiElement)
{
    uiElement.enabled = false;
}
```

But don't use find by name, it is very slow. Make references to your elements and pass them.